# The "action" of outer automorphisms of $S_6$ on subsets of $S_6$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions, symmetric-groups

Let $S_6$ be equipped with the natural action on $\{1,2,\dots,6\}$. For $1\leq i,j\leq 6$, define subsets:
$$X_{j\to i}:=\{\sigma\in G\,\mid \sigma(j)=i\}.$$
Let $X:=\{X_{j\to i}\mid 1\leq i,j\leq 6\}$. Suppose that $\psi\in \mathrm{Aut}(S_6)$. Consider the set:
$$\psi X_{j\to i}:=\{\psi(\sigma)\mid\sigma\in X_{j\to i}\}.$$
*If $\psi$ is inner, then the $\psi$ is a permutation on $X$.*

*Proof:* Let $\psi(\sigma)=t\sigma t^{-1}$ for $t\in S_6$. Let $\sigma\in X_{j\to i}$. Consider
$$\begin{aligned}
\psi(\sigma)(t(j))&=t\sigma t^{-1}t(j)=t\sigma(j)=t(i),
\end{aligned}$$
that is $\psi(\sigma)\in X_{t(j)\to t(i)}$.

**Question: What  does $\psi$ do to the $X_{j\to i}$ when it is an outer automorphism of $S_6$? Is any nice description available?**

I can see that we don't in general have stability. For example, both $(12),(23)\in X_{4\to 4}$, but there is an outer automorphism that sends $(12)$ to $(12)(34)(56)$ and $(23)$ to $(13)(25)(46)$, so it splits up $X_{4\to 4}$.

Note that the $\psi X_{j\to i}$ are subsets of size $5!$ in $S_6$.

Comment: @user297024 this sounds very good. I will have to wrap my head around it and get back to you. It feels like a cogent discription.

Comment: @user297024 we have six stabiliser subgroups $X_{aa}\subset S_6$. Is it the case that $\psi(X_{aa})$ is a copy of transitive $S_5\subset S_6$? And each $\psi(X_{aa})$ is conjugate to $\psi(X_{bb})$? I think if yes that is probably enough for your comment to be converted to an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user297024 in the comments, something indeed can be said. We use $X_{ji}:=X_{j\to i}$ and $P_{ji}=\psi(X_{ji})$.

Note for any $1\leq k\leq 6$, $X_{kk}$ is a stabiliser subgroup $S_5\subset S_6$. The image of $X_{kk}$ under an outer automorphism, $P_{kk}=\psi(X_{kk})$ is a transitive $S_5\subset S_6$.

An element $t\in X_{ji}$ gives rise to an element $\psi(t)\in P_{ji}$ and this (or maybe its inverse) conjugates $P_{ii}$ and $P_{jj}$, and similarly there are nice conjugations between $P_{ij}$ and $P_{kl}$ in the cases $i=k$, $j=l$ and $i\neq k$, $j\neq l$.